# SQL server database on thick browser based client side without full sql installation - is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, web-applications, thick-client

I would like to build thick client using web browser, Silverlight and some database mechanism.
What do I mean? I would like to have some database on client side which interface is web browser. Is there a way to create somehow a temporary db file or structure on client side that client can use offline without connecting to central sql server and central database?
The assumption is that client doesn't have to install sql server on his machine and client don't have to install anything (besides silverlight for UI purposes) on it's side.

There is one more assumption. I have to be able to replicate data between central SQL Server 2008 and this db on thick client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SQL Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express.aspx) on the client, BUT you would have to install it. There is also [SQL Server Compact 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx):

> SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 is a free,
>   easy-to-use embedded database engine
>   that lets developers build robust
>   Windows Desktop and mobile
>   applications that run on all Windows
>   platforms including Windows XP, Vista,
>   Pocket PC, and Smartphone.

Otherwise, perhaps [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) might meet your needs:

> SQLite is a software library that
>   implements a self-contained,
>   serverless, zero-configuration,
>   transactional SQL database engine.

Comment: SQLite databases installation is as simple as copy pasting the db file. No separate install required. Pretty fast when small. Perfect for single user interactions. There is a pretty good .net library for it: sqlite.phxsoftware.com